# Resharper cache and GIT branches

Tags: git, resharper

guys, we switched to GIT some time ago from TFVC and now since all branches are in the same folder, when I am switching a branch Resharper starts to scan all files that were changed, and since I am switching a lot - it is very annoying.

Is there any way to make Resharper cache work correctly with branches?

Comment: This sounds like ReSharper is behaving correctly - if the files have changed, they need to be rescanned. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I want him to have separate cache of each branch and understand when I changed branch, so it can change its cache. But it sounds like some kind of a dream

Answer (score 3):

> since all branches are in the same folder

They don't have to be: [since Git 2.5, you can clone once, but checkout different branches in different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309).

So if you had a certain folder structure in TFVC, you can emulate it with Git and get back to a known behavior.

Comment: yes, this thing is almost what I need, but unfortunately it is not supported in VS2015 yet, so I can't use it to fast switch branches

Comment: @Immelstorn Then you need to manage multiple clone of the same repo in different folder: this is a workaround, but once VS2015 (which uses libgit2 + LibGit2Sharp) supports multiple working tree, you won't have to do that anymore. There a pending issue: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/3159. And a pending PR: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3436

Comment: not realy a solution, VS integrated tools will not track this, so the only way is to wait until worktrees will be implemented in VS

Comment: Agreed, but would that at least allow resharper to behave correctly?